# Convert polygons in shapefile to a NumPy array?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, import, numpy

I have a shapefile containing a number of polygons and all attributes being text. I'm trying to import the polygons into NumPy as an array where each polygon is represented as unique values.

I approach this by using gdal_rasterize to generate a GeoTIFF, which I then can convert to an array:

```
gdal_rasterize -a provcode -l longhurst PG:'host=localhost dbname=biomes' -tr 0.25 0.25 out.tif
```

and

```
tif = gdal.Open('out.tif')
tifArray = tif.ReadAsArray()
```

My problem is that all polygons get the same values since provcode is of type string. How can I make gdal_rasterize burn different values to represent different polygons?

Alternatively, is there a better way to do this conversion?

Comment: Please post a link to a sample of your data.

Comment: Do the polygons overlay?

Comment: No, the polygons don't overlay. Here is a link to the data: http://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php#longhurst

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an option in GDAL to rasterize polygons based on their attribute. But as far as I know it can not be string. But you can just add an attribute to your features and then give each feature a unique id. Let's say we call this field `ID`.

Open your shapefile

```
source_ds = ogr.Open("Longhurst_world_v4_2010.shp")
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()
```

Create the destination raster data source

```
pixelWidth = pixelHeight = 1 # depending how fine you want your raster
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()
cols = int((x_max - x_min) / pixelHeight)
rows = int((y_max - y_min) / pixelWidth)
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create('temp.tif', cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte) 
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixelWidth, 0, y_min, 0, pixelHeight))
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
NoData_value = 255
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)
band.FlushCache()
```

Here is the important part. Instead of setting a general `burn_value`, use `options`and set it to the attribute that contains the relevant unique value `["ATTRIBUTE=ID"]`

```
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, options = ["ATTRIBUTE=ID"])
```

Add a spatial reference

```
target_dsSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
target_dsSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
target_ds.SetProjection(target_dsSRS.ExportToWkt())
target_ds = None
```

Now you have your shapefile as a raster and can read it with `gdal.Open('temp.tif').ReadAsArray()`

[image]

Comment: I am sorry to bother you @ustroetz, I know it has been 3 years since you answered this question but I am having some trouble with your code as you can see here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227406/error-when-trying-to-open-a-shapefile-with-python. Can you explain me what am I doing wrong ?