# Reading a shapefile as an array using Python?

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, gdal, osgeo

I am trying to read a shapefile as an array with Python but I keep getting the same error:

```
Warning 1: Failed to find field ID on layer shapefile_maido_tipe, skipping.

ERROR 4: `temp.tif' not recognized as a supported file format.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/python/Desktop/programme_python_tipe/test.py", line 38, in <module>
    print layer('shapefile_maido_tipe.shx')
  File "C:/Users/python/Desktop/programme_python_tipe/test.py", line 36, in layer
    return gdal.Open('temp.tif').ReadAsArray()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ReadAsArray'
```

Here is the code that I got from [Convert polygons in shapefile to a NumPy array?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83251/convert-polygons-in-shapefile-to-a-numpy-array) :

```
import gdal
from osgeo import osr
from osgeo import ogr

def layer(shapefile):

    # 1) opening the shapefile
    source_ds = ogr.Open(shapefile)
    source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()

    # 2) Creating the destination raster data source

    pixelWidth = pixelHeight = 1 # depending how fine you want your raster
    x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()
    cols = int((x_max - x_min) / pixelHeight)
    rows = int((y_max - y_min) / pixelWidth)
    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create('temp.tif', cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte) 
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixelWidth, 0, y_min, 0, pixelHeight))
    band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    NoData_value = 255
    band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)
    band.FlushCache()

    # 4) Instead of setting a general burn_value, use optionsand set it to the attribute that contains the relevant unique value ["ATTRIBUTE=ID"]

    gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, options = ['ATTRIBUTE=ID'])


    # 5) Adding a spatial reference

    target_dsSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    target_dsSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    target_ds.SetProjection(target_dsSRS.ExportToWkt())


    return gdal.Open('temp.tif').ReadAsArray()

print layer('shapefile_maido_tipe.shx')

# maido is the name of a mountain
# tipe is the name of a french school project
```

Can you tell what am I doing wrong please ?

In this link you will find the shapefile I use: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7P95aWmH4DUYUZfcTVvbzF4bG8?usp=sharing

PS: The Reunion Island National Park is the owner and also the creator of the shapefile. I have to mention them every time I communicate this file.

Comment: is the shapefile in the same directory as the script? Perhaps you should try using the full path to the shapefile `gdal.Open('full/path/to/shapefile_maido_tipe.tif')`

Comment: Yes it is, I added `'C:\Users\python\Desktop\programme_python_tipe\shapefile_maido_tipe.shx'` and `'C:\Users\python\Desktop\programme_python_tipe\shapefile_maido_tipe.tif'` as you asked but I get the same error.

Comment: Your question title and code sample are a bit confusing, you are opening and reading a .tif raster image file not a shapefile.  Please update your question to clarify this.

Comment: I want to read a shapefile as an array and I am using a code from this link:http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83251/convert-polygons-in-shapefile-to-a-numpy-array. I edited the title and the code to show the steps. I thought it was creating a tif file with a shapefile so that I could get an array with ReadAsArray() but according to what you say it doesn't seem to do that. So I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script was generally correct, but you didn't change the name of the attribute field you wanted to rasterize.

In the example you posted, you set `['ATTRIBUTE=ID']` as field, but it doesn't exists in your shapefile. You only have `"Habitats"` and `"surface"` as fields, so you need properly edit the code.

Therefore, you needed to edit the folders for both shapefile and rasterized layers, and the crs.

I slightly edited the code in this way:

```py
import gdal
from osgeo import osr
from osgeo import ogr

def layer(shapefile):

    # 1) opening the shapefile
    source_ds = ogr.Open(shapefile)
    source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()

    # 2) Creating the destination raster data source

    pixelWidth = pixelHeight = 1 # depending how fine you want your raster
    x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()
    cols = int((x_max - x_min) / pixelHeight)
    rows = int((y_max - y_min) / pixelWidth)
    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(raster_path, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte) 
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixelWidth, 0, y_min, 0, pixelHeight))
    band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    NoData_value = 255
    band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)
    band.FlushCache()

    # 4) Instead of setting a general burn_value, use optionsand set it to the attribute that contains the relevant unique value ["ATTRIBUTE=ID"]
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, options = ['ATTRIBUTE=surface'])

    # 5) Adding a spatial reference
    target_dsSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    target_dsSRS.ImportFromEPSG(2975)
    target_ds.SetProjection(target_dsSRS.ExportToWkt())
    return gdal.Open(raster_path).ReadAsArray()


raster_path = 'C:/Users/path_to_the_rasterized_output/temp.tif'

shapefile = 'C:/Users/path_to_the_shapefile/shapefile_maido_tipe.shp'

print layer(shapefile)
```

and I think it is working by now because I obtain this rasterized layer (which overlaps the shapefile):

[image]

and this return from the `print layer(shapefile)` line (you see only '255' value because you set it as nodata value):

```py
[[255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 ..., 
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using QGIS: Raster > Convert > Rasterize.

Then I get a Geotiff file that I can read with `gdal`:

```
def Tif2Array(geo_tiff_file):
    return gdal.Open(geo_tiff_file).ReadAsArray()

sf = Tif2Array('shapefile_maido_tipe.tif')
print matshow(sf)
```

[image]